# Django process file before saving

Tags: python, django

I want to be able to process a file before saving in Django.  I wanted to do it in a way that would affect both default Django (like through admin interface) and DRF (which uses the `create` method in the serializer).

So I tried to overwrite the `save` method as below:

```
class Soundbite(models.Model):
    app_label = 'soundbite'

    name = models.CharField('name', max_length=32, null=False)
    audio = models.FileField('audio', upload_to='soundbites', null=False,
                             validators=[FileExtensionValidator(['mp3', 'wav', 'aac'])])
    duration = models.FloatField('duration', null=False, blank=True)blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.duration:
            storage: FileSystemStorage = self.audio.storage
            file = self.audio

            # process file, like get duration using ffmpeg and validate its a proper audio file.
            info = probe(storage.path(self.audio.name))
            duration = info['format']['duration']
            print(duration)
            self.duration = duration

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)  # Call the "real" save() method.
```

But I don't exactly know how to access the file before calling the super save method.  I can do it either by having a filesystem path with the file, or by reading the raw bytes of the file.

How would I access the file before saving to database?

Edit:

Someone suggested I try doing it in the views instead.  So I have the following:

```
class SoundbiteCreate(CreateView):
    model = Soundbite
```

And in my urls:

```
urlpatterns += re_path(r'^soundbite/add', SoundbiteCreate),
```

How do I access the file doing this method?

Comment: Well, I don't get the whole picture here. But a quick suggestion would be accessing the file in the views.py and make your operation there, then save the object. This could fulfil your statement of affecting both default Django and DRF.

Comment: @Jeffrey edited my question to consider your method.